# What is the benefit of providing a function to loadChildren?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

In the article [Understanding Modules and Services](https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a) the author says:

> if you organized your modules this way, you can still use the loadChildren keyword without actually Lazy Loading the module, as a proof that your module is independent and well-structured:

This is the code:

```
//Within contacs.module.ts
//Doesn't it need an export?
function contactsEntryPoint() {
    return ContactsModule();
}

//Within the app-routing.module.ts
{
    path: 'contacts',
    loadChildren: contactsEntryPoint
}
```

Does anyone understand what this is trying to illustrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is setting up the code for lazy-loading; but the program *actually* eager-loads the module.

The reason for doing so (as presented), is to ensure that you don't have any inter-module dependencies (especially singleton providers!).

Comment: So just to be clear does it do that without the preloading strategy, or do we also need to set the `preloadingStrategy` to `preloadAllModules`?

Comment: @Ole Preloading strategy only affects it if you are *actually* lazy loading (it causes lazy-loaded modules to be loaded in the background after bootstrapping)

Comment: OK so if the only feature module is the contacts module is there any difference between eager loading (Which I assume is triggered without a preloading strategy?) and the `preloadAllModules` strategy?

Comment: If `ContactsModule` is the one being bootstrapped then no. If there is an `AppModule` then yes it changes when the `ContactsModule` is loaded.

Comment: Yes the latter part of your explanation is what I'm referring to.  If we have an `AppModule` and a `ContactsModule` only, and we don't set any preloading strategies, do we still effectively get the `preloadAllModules` strategy by using a function as the value for the `loadChildren` configuration property?

Comment: No. Using a function means it loaded *before* the application bootstraps. Using the preload strategy means it loads after.

Comment: OK - So by putting the function there the module is essentially compiled in with the rest of the application and it's all loaded on the first load?  In other words there is only a single request for all application modules?

Comment: @Ole Yes; it makes your main bundle bigger (meaning initial fetch will take longer) but you don't have to fetch a separate bundle later.

Comment: AWESOME!!  Thanks for hanging with me and clarifying that!